# How to query browser menubar visibility in Firefox (or other browsers)

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, menubar

I want to check if the **Browser Menu Bar** is absent.

There is a ***ReadOnly*** property:

```
window.menubar.visible
```

so this should be as elementary as:

```
if (window.menubar.visible !== true) {

  [... CODE HERE...]
}
```

However:

If I maximise the window using F11 such that the menubar no longer displays,  `window.menubar.visible` still returns `true`.

Further:

If I right-click on the menubar and deselect it, so it no longer displays,  `window.menubar.visible` still returns `true`.

In fact, I cannot find a single action which will enable `window.menubar.visible` to return `false`.

Is `window.menubar.visible` not only ***ReadOnly*** but *also* ***Immutable*** ?

---

**N.B.** *I am using **Firefox 105.0.1** - I usually try to get things working in Firefox first, so I have not yet tried Brave, Chrome etc.*

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/menubar
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/statusbar
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/locationbar
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/toolbar
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/personalbar
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollbars

Comment: **Why** are you doing this?

Comment: Because I believe that web-applications should not care about the user's web-browser at all. Secondarily, because it looks to me like you're trying to do visitor browser fingerprinting... Thirdly, if you want to re-layout your page based on available space then there are better ways (such as media-queries, container-queries, `window.innerHeight`, etc).

Comment: ...if you're going to do that then you've got _dozens_ of combinations of different browser and OS combinations - not to mention the risk of content becoming stale overnight when browser-vendors push out an update to all your visitors. Personally I wouldn't bother - I assume if someone's on my website/webapp then they already know how to use their web-browser.

Comment: From the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#dom-window-menubar-dev). -- _Returns true if the **top-level browsing context is not a popup**; otherwise, returns false._

Comment: @Christopher Makes sense - Firefox hasn't had a real menubar for years.

Comment: Thank you, @Christopher - Ahhh... so is `window.menubar.visible` more like `window.menubar.potentiallyVisible`  or `window.menubar.theoreticallyPossible` ?

Comment: @Rounin-StandingwithUkraine modern browsers try to keep almost all settings hidden (or prompt the user to grant access) from the javascript engine to increase the end users privacy. You might want to take a look at [this issue on github](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4431) too.